# Strange Entity Framework behavior - Adds double when IEnumerable is not List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Repository base class which has the following method:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            }
        }
```

I call it like so:

```
uow.UserPermissions.AddRange(permissions);
```

where UserPermissions is a repository that inherits from the base.

I am seeing some strange behavior that I cannot explain when permissions is not a list. For example when I try something like this:

```
var permissions = permissionDtos.Select(dto => new UserPermission()
                {
                    ...
                });

                uow.UserPermissions.AddRange(permissions);
```

entity framework adds twice as many permissions to the db as there are  permissionDtos. However, if I add a ToList() at the end of the select statement, the strange behavior goes away. I also noticed that when I comment out the forEach loop (that modifies the context entries state) in the Repository.AddRange() method, the strange behavior goes away as well (even without adding the ToList()).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.That is why this behaviour.When you do this `Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);`,it Adds the given collection of entities into context underlying the set with each entity being put into the Added state such that it will be inserted into the database when `SaveChanges` is called.You can see it on [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220168(v=vs.113).aspx).
So you don't need to do it again inside the `foreach` loop.When you remove either one, your method should be OK.

You can try as shown below.

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on why you get twice as many entries, it's because of how `IQueryable<T>` works.

Every time you enumerate a query, the query is re-executed. In fact, the query is not actually performed at all until it gets to the loop somewhere inside `Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);`

Internally, AddRange is enumerating the query results, which in your case will select all rows in the table behind permissionDtos and project these into new UserPermission objects.

Then, in your foreach loop, you're executing the query a second time by enumerating it again, which again selects all rows and projects them as new UserPermission objects.  Since you're projecting these results, the framework isn't able to reuse the objects it created during the first execution of the query.  If you were directly enumerating a `Set<TEntity>` twice, it would still execute the query twice, but it would be able to re-use the already materialized objects.

In the case where you use `ToList()`, you're forcing the query and projection to happen immediately and you're no longer saving the query itself - `permissions` in this case is no longer a query but a list of your already-projected items.

Sampath has already answered that your foreach loop is redundant - adding the entities to the context will mark them as added, and setting the state to added will add them to the context (the only difference between the two being in how related entities accessible through navigation properties are treated).  Even in the List case, you're doing an unnecessary loop.